# re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0 when installing via pip

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-requests, registry

i am relatively new to programming, and I ran into a problem. I have installed Python 3.7 and pip 10.0, but when I try to do something such as installing virtualenv, a bunch of error messages appear. I resulted to using easy_install, but the problem using pip is still persistent. My only guess is that maybe some part of pip didn't install properly, but I tried unsuccessfully tried uninstalling and installing again.

Comment: Include errors in your post, otherwise we can't guess what's the problem here.

Comment: The message is very long but here is the first snippet:                          


Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\"name"\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\"name"\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)

Comment: If it _very_ long, try use any service to save text like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/). Otherwise, include latest messages from traceback, that will typically contain exact reason exception was raised.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PW88m7MH

Comment: Is **"name"** your User name or you just replaced your real user name with this? I wonder what can cause this regex error and this is only thing that can come to my mind.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I just replaced my username with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [failing code](https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/v2.20.0/requests/utils.py#L80) is testing the `proxyOverride` settings in your computer's registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` under `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`.

`proxyOverride` appears to be a semi-colon-separated string, and apparently one of the values in the string starts with opening parenthesis that is not matched by a closed parenthesis, so something like:

`"ProxyOverride"="(www.foo-;*.bar.com"`

It is this unmatched parenthesis that is causing the error:

`File "c:\users\"name"\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\utils.py", line 74, in proxy_bypass_registry
    if re.match(test, host, re.I):
...
re.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0`

If your computer is on a network supported by your IT department you should ask them whether the values in the `proxyOverride` key are valid, and whether the offending parenthesis can be removed.

If you are your own IT department you could try to edit the registry yourself, but bear in mind that editing the registry should be done with great care, and that you should take a backup of the registry first, and know how to restore the registry from backup if it is required.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue, in case anyone else has the same problem I thought it was worth mentioning that my issue was caused by Autodesk Fusion 360. This is 3D CAD software that uses the cloud, and it adds a bunch of values with parentheses to the ProxyOverride registry variable mentioned by snakecharmerb:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings "ProxyOverride"`

The values DID have closing parentheses, so I'm not sure why Python threw the error.  Regardless, after I removed the Autodesk related values temporarily, pip worked fine.  I put the values back into the registry after I was done and will have to remember this workaround in the future when I want to use pip.